# What test should be used for two non-independent groups of different N?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence

This is my first question so apologies for any problems with it.

I am carrying out an experiment which involved counting the number of people using the stairs or the elevator during a 30 minute period, on the same day in consecutive weeks (this test is being performed in a university building where it can be assumed that similar people would be present on both days). However, the N recorded is different on the different days. The numbers are in the 300-400 range for each day (4 sets of data were recorded to compare two different days in two different weeks to account for possible differences between days).

What would be an appropriate test to use in this instance? Initially, I thought of the two sample test for proportions, but this requires an independent sample, which goes against what we are trying to test (the effect of a nudge on a similar group). McNemar also doesn't seem to work given the differences in N.

What test should I use in this case? Given that some people would be in both groups of the same day (attending a class for instance) the groups are not independent, but neither are they entirely non independent given that there would also be many people that only were tested on one of the two days. Really stuck here and any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about random effects logistic regression, with Person as a random effect; and day, and week  as fixed effects? That should take care of the dependence. Your research hypotheses perhaps might involve interactions among the fixed effects. If you don't have a Person label then I am also stuck.